# Porting my android game to ios... Use engine for that?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I created a game on android (and took many months)  due to the long list of feature (and I I did it natively).

Now I want to port this game to ios. After a lot of research, I decided to move to a game engine (unity) which I can maintain one code base for both ios and android (plus I don't have to learn objective c)

My question is, is this the right path? I mean I am having hard time believing that I need to recode everything in unity and I was wondering if there is a solution that I am not seeing.

Please help a fellow developer. Thanks

Comment: You're better off asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: snake, this is a question for gamedev.com.  Note that as a factual matter, your best bet at this point is to **simply doit in native iOS**.  You'll have no problem using iOS if you can use Android, any good programmer has to be fresh in both.  Get a Mac, click "Xcode" and away you go.

Comment: "I am having hard time believing that I need to recode everything in unity" then you must never have seen a computer before?  :)  What do you mean?  Why would there possibly be anything at all shared between two so utterly different paradigms of platform?  Yes, obviously, you have to start over.

Comment: Unity produces codes for multiple platform. I was not looking to run my Java android purly on ios. I know they are different. But I was wondering if there was a tool that would let me keep most of my Java code but adds interfaces   so it acts as intermediate layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when developing apps, you have to plan for a cross platform solution such as Xamarin, a web Cordova / Phonegap app or the Unity game engine (2D / 3D).

You can't tranform your APK file to build an iOS app instantly.

On the other hand, tools exist to convert java class to C# one :
http://codecall.net/2014/03/27/best-tools-to-convert-java-to-c-source-code/

Good luck :)